# Where did react install `invariant` lib?

Tags: reactjs

I am reading the react source code, and saw it was importing invariant library as `var invariant = require('invariant')`. But I didn't see it specify `invariant` library in package.json, my question is where this lib comes from?

Comment: which version of the react source code are you looking at?

Comment: 0.14-stable @sn_92

Comment: Also if you're using yarn, I think you can do `yarn why invariant` and it should show who depends on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you were looking in the source code of 0.14-stable, i found a dependecy of fbjs in the package.json of the react package: "fbjs": "^0.6.1",
(https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0.14-stable/packages/react/package.json).

In fbjs version 0.6.X, invariant is included in the **forks_ ([https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/0.6.x/src/__forks](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/0.6.x/src/__forks__/invariant.js)**/invariant.js), so my best guess is that it's included via there.

I'm not a 100% sure this is the case though, this is just theoretical (i didn't debug)

In v.0.13-stable, it's included here: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0.13-stable/src/vendor/core/invariant.js